# Bulma variables in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bulma

I have Bulma installed in my React.js project.

I've got a simple component where I'm trying to customize the color:

```
function Colortest() {
  return (
    <div>
      <section className="hero $black">
        <h1>Color Test</h1>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Colortest;
```

`is-primary` works, along with many other Bulma styles.  When I try to use some [variables](https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/variables/#initial-variables), however, it doesn't work.

Here are my "dependencies" in my root package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

This is my App.js file:

```
import "bulma/css/bulma.min.css";
import Header from './components/Header';
import Body from './components/Body';
import Colortest from "./components/Colortest";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Colortest />
      <Body />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Clearly, I'm missing something simple.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Bulma uses Sass variables](https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/variables/#:%7E:text=Bulma%20uses%20Sass%20variables)

To use variables with Bulma, you have to install & configure SASS, which is a CSS compiler, in your project.

You may check [bulma-start](https://bulma.io/bulma-start/) for a starter project which has these dependencies configured.

After having these dependencies installed, you have to write your own `.scss` or `.sass` file like

```
// styles.scss file
@import "bulma/bulma.sass";

.colortest {
  color: $white;
  background-color: $black;
}
```

or, `.sass` file as

```
// styles.sass
@import "bulma/bulma.sass"

.colortest 
  color: $white
  background-color: $black
```

After this, you only have to import this style into your component like

```js
import "./styles.scss"
// or,
// import "./styles.sass"
```

check this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bulma-scss-hxsn4i) for a working sample.

### References:

- [bulma-start](https://bulma.io/bulma-start/)
- [codesandbox sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/bulma-scss-hxsn4i)
- [Learn SASS](https://sass-lang.com/guide)

Comment: Thanks very much.  Just so I'm clear, in order to use the variables listed here (https://bulma.io/documentation/layout/hero/), I have to set up a scss or sass file?

Comment: Yes. But since scss/sass isn't recognised by browser, you need a way to compile it to css too. You can do that manually or setup node-sass(as in bulma-start).